# Не работает bootstrap.min.js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

> Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function

Такую ошибку выдает
Что сделать?
на локальном сервере

Comment: Какой браузер? Есть-ли хоть одна строка скрипта, написанная вами?

Comment: Удалить этот файл и скачать новый.

Comment: сам ничего не написал.только скачал.браузер яндекс

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо подключить сперва jquery, до того места, где вы вставили скрипт бутстрапа

Comment: простите за тупость.это правда